# How to launch Siri using scheme url with xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, siri

I need to launch **Siri** (on a jailbroken device) through the `openUrl:` method.

For example

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Siri://"]];
```

Comment: Sorry for my english. 

Anyway, I wanted to know if there is a some trick to open Siri. 

Just see this video for understand. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pcpr5Z_1UAc&desktop_uri=/watch?v=Pcpr5Z_1UAc

For me no problem if i need to use cydia. Just I would like to know the way for make it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Also, Xcode is an IDE - a code editor. It's not a language or a platform.

Comment: Sorry for my english., i know the xcode is an IDE and not a language :P 

Anyway, I wanted to know if there is a some trick to open Siri. 

Just see this video for understand. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pcpr5Z_1UAc&desktop_uri=/watch?v=Pcpr5Z_1UAc

For me no problem if i need to use cydia. Just I would like to know the way for make it.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any *URL Scheme* for Siri, so I don't think you can open it that way.  Siri is also not a normal *App*, it's a library that's used by SpringBoard.

Anyway, if you want *another* way to open it, I would try looking at rpetrich's **libActivator** source code.

If [you look here, you'll see something similar](https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator/blob/master/LASimpleListener.x) to what you need.  The *Virtual Assistant* is "Siri".

```
- (BOOL)activateVirtualAssistant{   
   if ([%c(SBAssistantController) preferenceEnabled]) { 
      if ([%c(SBAssistantController) shouldEnterAssistant]) {
          SBAssistantController *assistant = (SBAssistantController *)[%c(SBAssistantController) sharedInstance];           
          if (assistant.assistantVisible)   
             [assistant dismissAssistant];          
          else {
             [(SpringBoard *)UIApp activateAssistantWithOptions:nil withCompletion:nil];
             return YES;
          }     
       }
   }    
   return NO;
}
```

Here, the code calls `activateAssistantWithOptions:withCompletion:`, which is a method in [the SpringBoard class itself](https://github.com/optimo/SpringBoard-iOS5-Headers/blob/master/SpringBoard-Class.h).

This technique, of course, is based on MobileSubstrate *hooking*.

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested this code.  Just looking at it, though, it seems to be what you need.

---

### Update:

This isn't using URL schemes, but I did figure out a different way to launch Siri, [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18671422/119114).

Answer (score 0):

There's no URL schema for Siri and there's no integration available at this time - there may be integration coming in iOS 7 but at this stage there is no way to perform this function.

Comment: Sorry for my english. 

Anyway, I wanted to know if there is a some trick to open Siri. 

Just see this video for understand. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pcpr5Z_1UAc&desktop_uri=/watch?v=Pcpr5Z_1UAc

For me no problem if i need to use cydia. Just I would like to know the way for make it.